# running python programs from a terminal multiple errors. P 12 Eric Matthes python crash course

Tags: python, syntax-error

```py
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 22:39:24) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

# Book says type this
>>> C:\> cd Desktop\python_work
```

my desktop file folder is named python_work
I saved program to PATH when downloading on windows

```py
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
>>> C: cd Desktop\python_work
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> C: cd desktop\python_work
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> C:\cd\Users\Nate\Desktop\python_work
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
>>> C:\cd\Users\Nate\Desktop\hello_world.py
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
>>> C:\ cd "Desktop\python_work"
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
>>> C: cd "Desktop\python_work"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> cd "Desktop\python_work"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> cd Desktop\python_work
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> cd Desktop\"python_work"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> cd "desktop"\python_work
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> cd\"desktop\python_work"
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
>>> cd\Desktop\python_work
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
>>> C: cd "Desktop\python_work"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> C:\> cd Users\Nate\Desktop\python_work
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
>>>
```

Please help

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Are you running `cd` on windows command prompt ?

Comment: running cd in python 3.8 32 bit  the goal of the activity is to access dir

Comment: I highly doubt it, if you can directly run `cd` command in python.

Comment: To run a python script open command prompt and then type in `python <script-path>`. e.g. `python C:\Users\Nate\Desktop\hello_world.py`

Comment: I just found a windows power shell installed on my laptop it works fine on this program but not on python window?   Directory: C:\Users\Nate\Desktop\python_work


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         1/6/2020  10:14 PM             28 hello_world.py


PS C:\Users\Nate\Desktop\python_work> python hello_world.py
Hello Python world!
PS C:\Users\Nate\Desktop\python_work>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your script through Python shell, then use the below command. There are other options as well. But you can not use `cd` command on Python.

```py
exec(open('C:\\Users\\Nate\\Desktop\\python_work\\hello_world.py').read())
```